# Problem in elementary number theory about prime numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I was looking at a packet of problems in elementary number theory, when I saw this question:

Show that $n$ is prime iff

$$\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}\,\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}\,\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\,\sum_{u=0}^{s}\left(1-\left(\cos\,\frac{(u!)^{r}\pi}{n}\right)^{2t}\right)=n $$

How would one solve this problem?

Comment: My first thought is that if the $r$ exponent weren't there, there would only be finitely many nonzero terms in the sum because the $u!$ term would eventually be both even and divisible by $n$. Can't see how that helps though.

Comment: As an addendum to that, I'm really tempted to try writing $n$ as a limit of a sequence depending on $r$ in a clever way ("clever" here meaning "such that the expression on the left hand side, with the limiting operation on $r$ removed, is equal to the expression on the right hand side, with the limiting operation on $r$ removed) (hopefully what I mean there is clear) and proceed from there, exploiting my first comment once the outermost limit is stripped. But how, or even if, I can do that is not at all clear to me. Gonna go play with this in Wolfram for a while.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617418/show-that-p-is-prime-if-the-following-limit-property-holds but with better typesetting.

Comment: It's definitely the same question, and the answer there is almost definitely correct so far as I can tell (funny how much easier it is to verify an answer than to come up with one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that:
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\left(\cos\,\frac{(u!)^{r}\pi}{n}\right)^{2t}=\chi_{\mathbb Z}\left(\frac{(u!)^{r}}{n}\right)=
\begin{cases}
1&\text{if $\frac{(u!)^{r}}{n}\in\mathbb Z$}\\
0&\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$$
thus
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow+\infty}\,\sum_{u=0}^{s}\left(1-\left(\cos\,\frac{(u!)^{r}\pi}{n}\right)^{2t}\right)=\sharp\{u\in\{0,\ldots,s\} : (u!)^{r}\notin n\mathbb Z\}$$
$$\lim_{s\to+\infty}\lim_{t\rightarrow+\infty}\,\sum_{u=0}^{s}\left(1-\left(\cos\,\frac{(u!)^{r}\pi}{n}\right)^{2t}\right)=\sharp\{u\in\mathbb N : (u!)^{r}\notin n\mathbb Z\}$$

Assuming $r$ to be a positive integer, we have:
$$\lim_{s\to+\infty}\lim_{t\rightarrow+\infty}\,\sum_{u=0}^{s}\left(1-\left(\cos\,\frac{(u!)^{r}\pi}{n}\right)^{2t}\right)=\sharp\{u\in\mathbb N : n\nmid (u!)^{r}\}$$.
For large $r$, we have $n\nmid (u!)^r$ if and only if there exists a prime $p$ such that $p\mid n$ and $p\nmid u!$. More over, $p\nmid u!$ if and only if $u<p$.
\begin{align}
\lim_{r\to+\infty}\lim_{s\to+\infty}\lim_{t\rightarrow+\infty}\,\sum_{u=0}^{s}\left(1-\left(\cos\,\frac{(u!)^{r}\pi}{n}\right)^{2t}\right)=
&\sharp\{u\in\mathbb N : \exists p\text{ prime }(p\mid n\wedge u<p)\}\\
&=\max\{p\text{ prime }:p\mid n\}
\end{align}

Clearly, $\max\{p\text{ prime }:p\mid n\}=n$ if and only if $n$ is prime.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you suppose there's any room for generalization to rings of integers of other number fields, or does the solution depend too closely on properties of the factorial that don't generalize (say, by replacing factorial with an appropriate falling factorial)?